# Use docker build step plugin in Jenkins docker container

Tags: plugins, jenkins, docker

I have a jenkins server inside a docker container:

I've edited the base image so I'm able to mount the docker sockets to my container and use the sockets as jenkins user.

```
docker run -d -u jenkins --name jenkins \
  -p 50000:50000 \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  --volumes-from jenkins-volume \ 
  --restart=always \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \ 
  test/jenkins:1.0
```

So I'm able to run commands such as `docker version` and `docker ps` in my jenkins container (in a shell).

Now I've installed the docker build step plugin.

My question is how can I have to use and configure this plugin?

In the global configuration I see:

- Docker installer (I would think I don't need that)
- Docker builder: Docker server REST API URL

So I don't know how to configure this.

When I just try to perform a docker command using the plugin in a Jenkins Job I get an error; I'm not able to save the configuration of the docker command inside my job and I see the following error in my logs on jenkins:

```
Error while serving http://ip:8080/job/docker-test/configSubmit
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor648.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
...
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: This page expects a form submission but had only {}
```

How can I configure this plugin inside a jenkins-docker container in which the docker sockets are mounted?

Answer (score 1):

1. Change docker daemon from unix socket to tcp/2375
2. In the Jenkins / Settings / Docker Builder / Docker URL section add docker rest-url on port 2375 (even if TEST doesnt work)

Put just 172.17.0.1:2375 (where 172.17.0.1 is the host running the docker daemon)

Comment: Tested with tcp with docker 1.12 and jenkins 2.32 I had to put tcp://172.17.0.1:2375 and test button worked